# Angular doesnt detect ajax loaded content by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, datatables

I have a Datatables table that has actions which call Angular functions. It works fine except when Datatables redraws when you change page or click on filters, then Angular doesnt detect the function calls.

What way can you tell angular to compile again the new ajax html loaded by Datatables?

Sample of tr loaded by Datatables via Ajax call:

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
   <td class="sorting_1">
      <a href="/admin/usuarios/ver/8149">8149</a>
   </td>
   <td>Jose</td>
   <td>Alarcon</td>
   <td class=" text-primary">jos3.4larc0n@gmail.com</td>
   <td>CLIENTE</td>
   <td>15/10/2016</td>
   <td>Activo</td>
   <td>
      <a ng-click="cambiarStatus($event)" data-id="8149" href="">Cambiar Status</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Sample function in angular:

```
 $scope.cambiarStatus = function(item){
     var id = item.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
     var url = urlBase + '/cambiarStatus';

     $http.post(url, {id: id})
          .success(function(data) {
             alertify.success('Se cambio el status del usuario #'+id);
                 setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},2000);
           })
          .error(function() {
                alertify.error('Error al cambiar status usuario.');
           });
     };
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: need more info!

Comment: you can use $scope.$apply() to tell angular that it needs to run a digest cycle.

Comment: Where do i add the $scope.$apply() in angular? how does it know the table was redrawn? @edo.n

Comment: Now that you have shown sample code, I am a little confused. I was under the impression that there is data loaded by jQuery ajax call, and since that would be external to angular, it needs to be notified. Hence the $scope.$apply() suggestion.

Comment: The code that loads the Ajax is done by Datatables....so I couldn't really show that code. You can assume that this TR is loaded by ajax @edo.n